# Vertical Align Bootstrap Badge and Text Inside Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.test {
    height: 58px;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">
    <span>TEXTHERE TEXTHERE</span> <span class="badge">1</span>
</button>
```

How to make the badge to be vertical aligned on the 2-row text?

Edit: target result [image]

Comment: What is the bootstrap version 3 or 4?

Comment: Please display us how do you want it to be (maybe some image)?

Comment: I added a pic above. :)

Comment: @Rahul version 3. Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I have added this css:

```
.test .text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```css
.test {
  height: 58px;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.test .text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="test">
    <span class="text">TEXTHERE TEXTHERE</span><span class="badge">1</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This works thanks! Just 1 question, what if it was a `<span>` instead of `<button>`?

Comment: I mean if I try using `span`, all children weren't vertically aligned middle. I know this is already beyond my initial question but I'm just curious :)

Comment: If you used span then give it `display:block` or `display:inline-block`. so it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
        .badge{
            margin-left: 80px;
            margin-top: -29px;
        }
        .test {
            height: 58px;
            width: 130px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid 1px black;

        }
        .test .text {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 80%;
            margin-left: -30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="test">
        <span class="text">TEXTHERE TEXTHERE</span><span class="badge">1</span>
    </button>
</body>
```